# Hide PHP extension from second segment of url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using one htaccess code (Core PHP) to hide php extension from url and its working great but not true with second segment of url

for example if url is http://www.abc.com/somepage than my code is running great but if url is
http://www.abc.com/xyz/sompage than my code will fail.

here is my code of htaccess

```
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]

        # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
        RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]

        # Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
        RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $2.php [L]
```

Please help me to find out hte solution that no matter how much segments are there but it should take last segment as a php file

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing wrong the url segment `xyz/somepage` will actually map to this example: `index.php/somepage.php` this will not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.abc.com/xyz [nc]
RewriteRule !^(.*)$ !http://www.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```